# Should I `new` an object inside or outside of a loop?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm

Comparing `test1()` and `test2()` in the following code:

```
    class Test{
    //max value is a large number
    int max_value = 100*1000;

    public void test1(){
        for(int i=0; i<max_value;){
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append("String value");
            builder.append("append our value much time so will consume many memory");
        }
    }

    public void test2(){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i<max_value;i++){
            builder.append("String value");
            builder.append("append our value much time so will consume many memory");
            builder.setLength(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Which method would be better for our program? I think it is `test2()`, but in my project when I use code like `test2()`, my program takes twice as long to execute as `test1()`; why is this?

Usually `test1()` will create more objects than `test2()`, so will `test1()` use more memory? And for garbage collection how do I recover builder object in `test1()`?

Comment: It depends on how builder object is utilized further, in the code.

Comment: What are these times? Try to test it out without `builder.append` (because it ocurres in both cases). What is the result if you compare calling constructor and `builder.setLength(0)`?

Comment: when i use test1(); my program use time less than test2(), and my doubt is i create so many object in test1(), GC how to recover it.

Comment: builder object just use in every loop@DarshanMehta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Microbenchmark are strongly influenced on status of JVM prior of test**.

If to test your performances you ran both codes *one after the other* this can have a strong impact on the results.

So it is different calling

```
test1();
test2();
```

or

```
test2();
test1();
```

because in `test1` you use the whole free memory and it happens that `test2` needs to run the garbage collector.

---

For the internal implementation of `setLength` is better to use the second implementation (`test2`) considering only the performance problem.

Remember that **performances are not all**. Changing the length of the `StringBuilder` is not intuitive so it is easy from a programmer point of view to misunderstand the second implementation. **Often a code more readable is better than a code more performant**.

Comment: only one method will be call, there are two methods can implements my business, i doubt which one will be better

Comment: in test1(), every time when i call this method, i will create an object, is GC will recover these object and how? and is it test2() better than test1(), beginning i think test2() better than test1(), in actually test2() will use more time than test1(), so this is my doubt

Comment: I know... but I don't know how you tested the performances of each of them. Often people creates a main method and call them one after the other.

Comment: in my business, we have a nested loop and i need do my logic in the inner loop and both inner and outside loop need loop so many times.

Comment: Garbage collections happens only when needed depending on the parameters of garbage collector. It can happens that a method use a lot of memory but the garbage collector doesn't start. The next method needs less memory, but no free memory is available so the garbage collector starts to free not used memory.

Comment: if we in concurrent multi-thread env, and thread1 is calling test1(), another thread2 will be called test1() and now GC will recover memory resource in thread1? @Davide Lorenzo MARINO

Comment: Multithread doesn't affect directly the garbage collector. Obviously an object can be garbage collected only if there is no reference to it in any of the running threads. But if this is the situation there is no difference if that object was lastly used by the main thread of by another thread.

Comment: thanks a lot, you help me to understand the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM is damn good with [lots of small objects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149563/should-we-avoid-object-creation-in-java). Which is what you have in `test1`.

In `test2` any optimizations the VM can do are throw away as it has to zero the backing array in `StringBuilder`.

But that is not the end of the story. Micro benchmarks are hard to get right, and the results will not be right on every platform. So rather than worry too much about them, write readable code (IMO `test1`). That way when the profiler tells you "this is what takes so much time" you can more easily optimize it.